# Using read.table()

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to open a file in a for loop with read.table(). When I pass the path variable file in read.table(), the path changes: the directory variable is omitted. I searched for similar issues and couldn't find a relevant case.
The code:

```
directories <- list.dirs('directory_path', recursive = T)
for (directory in 1:length(directories)){
  list <- list("File_0", "File_1")
  for(file in 1:length(list)){
    directory = directories[directory]
    file = paste(directory, list[file], sep = '/')
    read.table(file, colClasses = c(rep("character", 2), rep("NULL", 1)),
               header = T)
    output_path <- paste(directory, file, sep = '/')
    write.table(data, output_path, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE)
  }
}
```

If I remove the read.table() command and instead type print(file), all the paths are printed correctly.

The content of files I wish to open:

```
name    column_1    column_2
BME_RS00005 878 878
BME_RS00010 257 257
BME_RS00020 2511    2511
BME_RS00025 2611    2611
BME_RS00030 3886    3886
BME_RS17490 1494    1494
BME_RS00035 5922    5922
BME_RS00040 265 265
BME_RS00045 220 220
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring from your code that your directory structure looks like this:

```
├── directory_1
│   ├── File_0
│   └── File_1
├── directory_2
│   ├── File_0
│   └── File_1
├── directory_3
│   ├── File_0
│   └── File_1
```

The best thing is to get all the files into one vector before iterating over them:

```r
directories <- list.dirs(directory_path, recursive = T)
files  <- c("File_0", "File_1")

full_paths  <- as.character(
    sapply(files, function(x) paste0(directories, "/", x))
)
full_paths

# [1] "directory_1/File_0" "directory_2/File_0" "directory_3/File_0" "directory_1/File_1"
# [5] "directory_2/File_1" "directory_3/File_1"
```

Now you have a vector of files you can just read them in.

You could probably do the next bit with `lapply` but I'm not sure what you're doing in your loop. Now you have updated the question to say you want to delete a column, just do this:

```
for(infile in full_paths){
    df  <- read.table(
        infile,
        colClasses = c(rep("character", 2), rep("NULL", 1)),
        header = T
    )
    # ... do stuff here
    df[["column_2"]]  <- NULL
    outfile = paste0(infile, "_new")
    write.table(df, outfile, sep = '\t', quote = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The goal is to remove a column from the tables and save them to files. I add the missing code to the question.

Comment: OK... I've updated my response. Let me know if this works - don't see why it wouldn't if the file structure is correct.

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue of read.table() getting 'directory/file_1' instead of 'directory/sub-directory/file_1' .

Comment: It is hard to help without knowing what your actual file tree looks like. Can you post that?

Comment: The tree you suggested is correct.